# Find value of XML node with respect to matching another node value

Tags: xml, groovy

I have the following XML file :

```
<0>
    <title>The Little Hours</title>
    <year>2017</year>
    <imdbid>tt5666304</imdbid>
    <scid>10080</scid>
    </0>
    <1>
    <title>CarGo</title>
    <year>2017</year>
    <imdbid>tt6680792</imdbid>
    <scid>10079</scid>
</1>
<2>
    <title>My Little Pony: The Movie</title>
    <year>2017</year>
    <imdbid>tt4131800</imdbid>
    <scid>10078</scid>
</2>
<3>
    <title>Amityville: The Awakening</title>
    <year>2017</year>
    <imdbid>tt1935897</imdbid>
    <scid>10077</scid>
</3>
<4>
    <title>6 Days</title>
    <year>2017</year>
    <imdbid>tt4703048</imdbid>
    <scid>10076</scid>
</4>
```

I want to be able to get the value "6 days" by finding `<scid>10076</scid>`.

Here is what I have so far...

```
{xml = new XmlSlurper().parse(folder/'/mov.xml');
xml.findAll { it.@scid == fn }
}
```

**fn** is **10076**

This only returns the title for all 4 nodes. How would I be able to find the value of the `<title></title>` tag, using the value of `<scid></scid>` ?

Comment: please check the solution to see if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there except minor errors. `@` is used to access the `attribute` of an xml element or node; where as element can be accessed directly `.elementName` as shown below:

Use below to achieve the same:

```
def fn = '10076'
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parse('/file/path/to.xml')
//Use findAll if you are expecting multiple titles; this returns a list of all titles matching scid is 10076
println xml.'**'.findAll { it.name() == 'scid' && it.text() == fn}*.parent()*.title*.text()
```

If you are expecting `scid` element value is unique always, you need not to use `findAll`; instead use `find` method; so that you always get single `title`, not a like above result.

```
println xml.'**'.find { it.name() == 'scid' && it.text() == fn}.parent().title.text()
```

You can quickly try it online <kbd>[demo](https://ideone.com/mL0Owz)</kbd>

Comment: @Dade, no problem. If that is helped, appreciate up vote & [accept it as answered](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Hey sorry, had to delete my comment as I didn't know it would submit it via the ENTER button. I will add another comment with what I have now. I didn't have time until now to try it out

Comment: So my problem is, my XML file is really big, over 47,000+ lines. So what I do is use 
`def xml = new XmlSlurper().parse('/file/path/to.xml')` 
to read the xml file. Then I use your code
 `println xml.'**'.find { it.name() == 'scid' && it.text() == fn}.parent().title.text()` to display the title. However, there is an error/warning saying this : `expression yields empty value the entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference`

Comment: I am trying to use this little piece of code in a software called FileBot if that helps at all. I am trying to rename multiple files using FileBot

Comment: @Dade, I would first request you at least try the demo to see how it is working for the sample xml you have provided in the question.

Comment: I changed my XML format to match your example, where it has `<record></records>` now. I also added the `<root>` tags to it as well

Comment: @Dade, I did not get you. You haven't confirmed if you have tried the demo and see working as you needed.

Comment: Yes, I have tried the demo and it is working just fine. It is just not working in my environment. I am not sure if I can post links, so here is what it looks like : `https://i.imgur.com/jsOxX0u.png`

fn is already defined in the program as 10076

Comment: @Dade. Why are you putting code between `{ .. }`? If you look at the solution, you may notice that is not there and you missed to define `def fn = '10076'` too?

Comment: Because I am running this Groovy code in a software called FilelBot. All Groovy commands must be enclosed in a { .. } or else it won't work.

Comment: Ok, Have you defined `fn` value?

Comment: fn value is a pre-defined term by the FileBot program. If the program is working on a file name 10076, fn is =  10076, so I can use fn and it will display the file name. like so : `https://i.imgur.com/6af3kPx.png`

Comment: I do not know or heard anything about `FileBot`. But the groovy code is correct as you noticed in the demo. Is your actual xml is different from the sample you provided?

Comment: Okay thanks for your help! i will have to contact the maker of FileBot. I will mark this as solve as your code is working just fine! but just not in this program. I really mean it, thank you very much!